# Integer to string optimized function?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, c++11, integer

I have currently this function to convert an unsigned integer to a string (I need a function that works on non-standard types like `__uint128_t`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <typename UnsignedIntegral>
std::string stringify(UnsignedIntegral number, const unsigned int base)
{
    static const char zero = '0';
    static const char alpha = 'A';
    static const char ten = 10;
    std::string result;
    char remainder = 0;
    do {
        remainder = number%base;
        result += (remainder < ten) ? (zero+remainder) : (alpha+remainder-ten);
        number /= base;
    } while (number > 0);
    std::reverse(std::begin(result), std::end(result));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout<<stringify(126349823, 2)<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize this code ?

Comment: One way would be to store the set of possible "digits" as a static array (0 through 9 followed by A through Z) and index that, rather than using a conditional to decide whether to use a numeral or letter. Also, for commonly used bases like 2, 8, 10 and 16 you can provide template specializations with optimized algorithms for those bases.

Comment: This looks like a better fit for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it's about improving code which works, not about fixing code which doesn't.

Comment: Um... `sprintf`? Do you really expect to gain more than 0.5% from optimizing that?

Comment: @Angew Wouldn't you say that not meeting a performance requirement counts as not working?

Comment: Following @dvnrrs, when the base is a power of 2, use bitwise operations rather than the very costly % and /. You can also avoid the recourse to % by using the identity A % B = A - (A / B) * B (you trade a % for a *). And when the base is known not to exceed 10, there are no hex digits.

Comment: @Damon A specialized function just for stringifying a number can do much, *much* better than `sprintf`. `sprintf` is a general string formatting algorithm and has to do a *lot* of work that a specialized function doesn't have to do.

Comment: @dvnrrs: Right, such as optimizing by doing a dozen dynamic memory allocations per converted number. But even assuming you could write a conversion function that is 500% faster than `sprintf` into a static buffer, and neglecting the fact that the code example uses iostream for output, do you really think it would make any measurable difference? On my no-special 4 year old computer, `sprintf` does about 800,000 integer/string conversions per second. How many more do you need? (and for reference, the above code runs about 60% _slower_ on my machine).

Comment: @Damon The question is what does the OP need. He posted a question and I (partially) answered it. I fully agree that optimization should only be done *when necessary* and that unneeded optimization is both wasted work and a common pitfall. The OP did not ask whether or when he should optimize, so apparently he has already made that decision. If he wants to know if it's necessary he can post another question. I am not his mother.

Comment: @Angew I don't quite agree: performance optimization can be a legitimate line of questioning here, especially if framed in complexity requirements or presented with some pathological assembly from the OP code. The CodeReview sister site is more aimed at style in all its dimensions (including also performance sometimes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to read this article by Alexei Alexandrescu, where he talks about low-level optimizations by using a (fixed-radix) int to string conversion as an example:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920

Keep in mind that the most important thing when optimizing is always profiling.

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing is avoiding multiple heap allocations, which can be done by either `result.reserve(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(Integral))` (the largest possible string being base 2) or building the string into a local array first and then creating the `std::string` from it.  Even with that, I agree with @SebastianRedl; you cannot optimize w/o measuring.  Also, your code doesn't take into account negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky you will be inside "short string optimization" buffer size for the string. If not, then you incur a **dynamic memory allocation** which is probably at least an order of magnitude slower than the conversion code. So first, get rid of that `std::string`, and add support for determining suitable raw buffer size.

When you've done that, get rid of the **branching** caused by the choice operator. Table lookup might be faster (or not). But it's also possible to use bit tricks such as converting small negative number to all one's by bit-shifting right, then use that as a mask.

Finally, instead of **reversing** the result you can build it directly backward from the end of the supplied buffer, and produce pointer to start as function result.

---

All this said, do remember to **MEASURE**.

For optimizations that logically can't be significantly worse than the original, such as the above, measuring might be more work than simply doing the optimizations coding. But when you have done the obvious and you're interested in eeking out the last bit of performance, measuring is necessary. Also, for most programmers measuring is necessary just in order to not waste time on completely unnecessary optimization, or introducing new inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a way to optimize the code. There is indeed a faster way than pure digit-by-digit conversion: you can work with groups of digits, i.e. in a base that is a power of the desired base.

For example:

Base 2 -> base 256 (8 bits at a time)

Base 8 -> base 512 (3 octal digits at a time)

Base 10 -> base 100 (2 decimal digits at a time)

Base 16 -> base 256 (2 hexadecimal digits at a time)

You will need to pre-tabulate the representation of the digit combinations as short ASCII character strings. And you will need to add special processing of the high-order digits to avoid or undo leading zeroes.

```
OctalStrings[]= { "000", "001", "002" ... }
```

But the main loop will remain of the form:

```
do
  Q= N / Base
  R= N - Q * Base
  N= Q
  Insert(Strings[R])
while N>0
```

or, for a binary base:

```
do
  R= N & (Base - 1)
  N= N >> LgBase
  Insert(Strings[R])
while N>0
```

You can also do the conversion directly left-to-right by precomputing all powers of the base and using quotient/remainder.

```
Base100Powers[]= { 1, 100, 10000, 1000000... }

do
  Q= N / Powers[k]
  N= N - Powers[k] * Q
  Append(Strings[Q])
  k--
while k>0
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is, I think, a more efficient version, I have just coded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template <bool Upper = true, 
          typename Char = char,
          Char Zero = '0',
          Char Nine = '9',
          Char Alpha = Upper ? 'A' : 'a',
          Char Zeta = Upper ? 'Z' : 'z',
          Char One = 1,
          Char Ten = Nine-Zero+One,
          Char Size = (Nine-Zero+One)+(Zeta-Alpha+One),
          typename... Types, 
          class = typename std::enable_if<
          (std::is_convertible<Char, char>::value) && 
          (sizeof...(Types) == Size)>::type>
constexpr std::array<char, Size> alphabet(const Types&... values)
{
    return {{values...}};
}

template <bool Upper = true, 
          typename Char = char,
          Char Zero = '0',
          Char Nine = '9',
          Char Alpha = Upper ? 'A' : 'a',
          Char Zeta = Upper ? 'Z' : 'z',
          Char One = 1,
          Char Ten = Nine-Zero+One,
          Char Size = (Nine-Zero+One)+(Zeta-Alpha+One),
          typename... Types, 
          class = typename std::enable_if<
          (std::is_convertible<Char, char>::value) && 
          (sizeof...(Types) < Size)>::type>
constexpr std::array<char, Size> alphabet(Types&&... values)
{
    return alphabet<Upper, Char, Zero, Nine, Alpha, Zeta, One, Ten, Size>
           (std::forward<Types>(values)..., 
            Char(sizeof...(values) < Ten ? Zero+sizeof...(values)
                                         : Alpha+sizeof...(values)-Ten));
}

template <typename Integral,
          Integral Base = 10,
          Integral Zero = 0,
          Integral One = 1, 
          Integral Value = ~Zero,
          class = typename std::enable_if<
          (std::is_convertible<Integral, int>::value) && 
          (Value >= Zero) && 
          (Base > One)>::type>
constexpr Integral digits()
{
    return (Value != ~Zero)+
           (Value > Zero ? digits<Integral, Base, Zero, One, Value/Base>()
                         : Zero);
}

template <bool Upper = true,
          typename Integral,
          std::size_t Size = digits<Integral, 2>()>
std::string stringify(Integral number, const std::size_t base)
{
    static constexpr auto letters = alphabet<Upper>();
    std::array<char, Size+1> string = {};
    std::size_t i = 0;
    do {
        string[Size-i++] = letters[number%base];
    } while ((number /= base) > 0);
    return &string[Size+1-i];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<stringify(812723U, 16)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It could be optimized more efficiently using the technique of Yves Daoust (using a base that is a power of the provided base).

Comment: "You think"? Timing numbers or I don't believe you.